# Running node.js tests locally in vstest.console.exe gives ... Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://nodejstestexecutor/v1

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get VSTS to run my Mocha unit tests, similar to how I've got them running in VS 2017.

I'm installed the [Node JS Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools) and VS Test Explorer *(after a restart)* picks up the tests, and runs them.

But I can't get a VSTS build task to run them ???

Tried going through the notes on NTVS about [running tests in VSTS](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Test-Explorer#running-tests-on-visual-studio-team-services) but no joy getting it to work.

Moved onto the section about [troubleshooting](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Test-Explorer#troubleshooting), and seeing if I can run the tests using my local `vstest.console.exe` ...

So far trying to run vstest ...

- Error: The imported project `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsTools.targets"` was not found
- *quick fix ...* added a copy of directory ... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Node.js Tools` ... to ... `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0`
- Error: The imported project `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"` was not found
- *quick fix* ... added a copy of directory ... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` ... to ... `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0`
- Error: Could not find a part of the path `C:\Repos\smc\BasicAzureExpress\BasicAzureExpress\ntvs\TestFrameworks`
- `quick fix` ... amend .nsproj to VS 2017 ... `<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>` and a directory `\TestFrameworks` under `\ntvs`

... and then have the error ... `Error: Missing generic test framework`

So I'm left puzzled as to why VS 2017 can run the tests, but `vstest.console.exe` won't

Comment: Do you use Hosted VS 2017 agent? Try to specify vstest.console.exe path in Visual Studio Test task. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform)

Comment: Note: You need to install test agent 2017.

Comment: What's the result after trying my solution?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Sorry, dragged off on urgent fix, so had to shelf investigation. Hope to get back to it next week.

Answer (score 0):

First, the **VSToolsPath** value is empty if running in command line, then uses `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)` path, but there aren’t necessary files of nodejs tool.

You can modify it like this (change Community to Professional if you are using vs2017 Professional):

```
<!--<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>-->
    <VSToolsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0</VSToolsPath>
```

Secondly, refer to these steps to run test on Hosted VS 2017 agent.

1. Modify project file (njsproj)

：

```
<!--<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>-->
    <VSToolsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0</VSToolsPath>
```

2. Copy **NodeJsTools** content in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017[Community, professional or enterprise]\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft to your ntvs folder
3. Add these files to source control and check in changes
4. Queue build with Hosted VS 2017 agent.